# How to set up a node.js development environment/server (Ubuntu 11.04)

Tags: node.js, development-environment

I am trying to set up a development environment for node.js. I assumed at first that it requires something similar to the traditional, "localhost" server approach. But I found myself at a loss. I managed to start a node.js hello world app from the terminal. Which doesn't looked like a big deal - having to start an app from the console isn't that hard. But, after some tweaking, I found out that the changes aren't shown in the browser immediately - you need to "node [appName here]" it again to run.

So, my question is:
Is there a software or a tutorial on how to create a more "traditional" development server on your local machine? Along with port listening setup, various configurations, root directories etc (things that are regular in stacks like XAMMP, BitNami or even the prepackaged Ubuntu LAMP). Since I'm new at node.js, I can't really be sure I'm even searching for the right things on google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at :
https://github.com/remy/nodemon

it'll allow you to do - nodemon app.js
and the server will restart automatically in case of failure.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I built a relatively small tool in NodeJS that allows me to start/stop/restart a NodeJS child process (which contains the actual server) and see/change configuration option and builds/versions of the application, with admin options available on a different tcp port. It also monitors said child process to automatically respawn it if there was a error (and after x failed attempts stops trying and contacts me).

While I'm prohibited from sharing source code, this requires the (built-in) `child_process` module, which has a `spawn` method that returns a child process I guess, which contains a `pid` (process id) which you can use with the `kill` method to kill said child process. Instead of killing it you could also work with `SIGINT` an catch it within your child application to first clean up some stuff and then exit. It's relatively easy to do.

Some nice reading material regarding this.

- http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.5/api/child_processes.html